# Set non root folder as website in IIS

Tags: iis

How do I set a non root folder as a web project in IIS?
I want the website to be
www.mysite.com/projectA

not
www.mysite.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this task.

Easiest way, go to the root of the website, create a subfolder called `Project A` and move everything there.

Alternatively, you can do it by changing the root of the website to a blank folder then creating a new `Virtual Directory` called `Project A` located at the old location.

Then there is the smartest way using the [`URL Rewrite`](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite) module, however this is the most complex method.

Answer (score 0):

You would create a new virtual directory in the IIS management console and specify the appropriate path.